# Data binding library - set ID via variable in <include /> tag

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I've recently found out that Google created Data Binding Library ([link](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/)) and I was wondering what are the limitation for data that might be passed to a layout variable through  tag?

In my project I have a requirement to have four ImageViews in a horizontal row with some text overlay and custom background that should have somewhat following structure

```
     ... layout above ...

[ img ] [ img ] [ img ] [ img ]  

     ... layout below ...
```

I know that there will always be 4 images so I just create them manually in XML file by duplicating items 4 times. This is definitely one of the worst ways to handle this, but I need each item to have unique speaking (?) ID (i.e "@+id/img_flower", "@+id/img_car") so I could set appropriate data to each of those later in code.

I realize that I might just go through child views of the container layout  and set data appropriately but if  might accept id as variable parameter, then the xml would shrink just to 4  elements with appropriate ID.

**layout/img.xml**

```
<layout ... >
   <data>
       <variable name="img_id", type="String"/>
   </data>
   <ImageView
         andorid:id="@{img_id}"
          ... />
```

**layout/my_view.xml**

```
<LinearLayout  ... >
  ...
  <include 
      layout="@layout/img,
      bind:img_id=@{"flower"} >
  <include 
      layout="@layout/img,
      bind:img_id=@{"car"} >
   ...
</LinearLayout>
```

But passing String as and ID resolves in compile-time exception as incompatible type for an ID field. The question is - is Data Binding library only limited to types as String, Int, Collections or can they be mixed with other values?